# How to fix "Invariant Objects are not valid as a react Child"

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

This is the error what i got, need help how to fix this..
thanks in advance ^^

[image]

```
_renderCategoryLists = async () => {
  const { categoryLists } = this.state
  categoryLists.map((category, index) => {
    return (
      <View key={index}>
        <Text>{category.category_id}</Text>
        <Text>{category.name}</Text>
        <Text>{category.image}</Text>
        <Text>{category.status}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  })
}
```

this is my code, and i return the function into the view

```
<View style={styles.panelKategori}> {this._renderCategoryLists()} </View>
```

Comment: Most likely, you are trying to dump an entire object into your JSX. Please add the relevant code, though

Answer (score 0):

```
_renderCategoryLists = async () => {
const { categoryLists } = this.state
categoryLists.map((category, index) => {
  return (
    <View key={index}>
      <Text>{category.category_id}</Text>
      <Text>{category.name}</Text>
      <Text>{category.image}</Text>
      <Text>{category.status}</Text>
    </View>
  )
})
```

}

Comment: this is my code, and i return the function into the view => 
<View style={styles.panelKategori}>
        {this._renderCategoryLists()}
      </View>

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `_renderCategoryLists` does not return anything. The return statement that you have there is for the lambda that you pass to `map`.

If you add a return statement to your function, it should be fine:

```
return categoryLists.map((category, index) => {
  ....
})
```

Comment: There is additionally the issue that you can't call async functions in `render`. It looks like that function has no need to be asynchronous, so try just removing the async keyword.

Comment: already removed, and the error now is : TypeError: categoryLists.map is not a function

Comment: In that case, `this.state.categoryLists` is not getting initialized as an empty array in the constructor. Make sure you are doing so.